# Bash script generating multiple log files. I want it to generate only one log file

Tags: linux, shell-script

I want the script to end after 1 iteration. It seems like it goes on loop and I had to kill it with CTR C. Don't know how to fix it.

```
[root@vPAS-Calipers lattice_private]# cat stat.sh
#!/bin/bash

DATE=`/bin/date +"%Y%m%d%H%M"`
#140 Caliper VM- Volte
sleep 2
./linux_machine_cli_firing.exp 172.9.9.14 "cd /root/cal/Product/run" "./cli -p  4001 " "show  call-mode statistics"
sleep 2
./linux_machine_cli_firing.exp 172.9.9.14 "cd /root/cal/Product/run" "./cli -p  4002 " "show  call-mode statistics"
sleep 2
./linux_machine_cli_firing.exp 172.9.9.14 "cd /root/cal/Product/run" "./cli -p  4003 " "show  call-mode statistics"
sleep 2

./stat.sh > stat-tps_${DATE}.txt
```

Result

```
stat-tps_202101271452.txt
stat-tps_202101271453.txt
stat-tps_202101271455.txt
```

Comment: Is that really your script? You are recursively calling it over and over? Or is the final line (`./stat.sh > stat-tps_${DATE}.txt`) not part of the script?

Comment: Get out of the habit of using ALLCAPS variable names, leave those as
reserved by the shell. One day you'll write `PATH=something` and then
[wonder why](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27555060/7552) 
your [script is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28310594/7552).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of the last line of the script:

```
./stat.sh > stat-tps_${DATE}.txt
```

This runs the script *again* with output redirected to a new file. (And when the script runs again, it'll finish by running itself again, etc).

I presume your intent is to redirect output from the `./linux_machine_cli_firing.exp` commands into a log file? If so, you probably want to log stderr as well. You can either redirect them individually for each command:

```
#!/bin/bash

date=$(/bin/date +"%Y%m%d%H%M")
#140 Caliper VM- Volte
sleep 2
./linux_machine_cli_firing.exp 172.9.9.14 "cd /root/cal/Product/run" "./cli -p  4001 " "show  call-mode statistics" >"stat-tps_${date}.txt" 2>&1
sleep 2
./linux_machine_cli_firing.exp 172.9.9.14 "cd /root/cal/Product/run" "./cli -p  4002 " "show  call-mode statistics" >>"stat-tps_${date}.txt" 2>&1
sleep 2
./linux_machine_cli_firing.exp 172.9.9.14 "cd /root/cal/Product/run" "./cli -p  4003 " "show  call-mode statistics" >>"stat-tps_${date}.txt" 2>&1
sleep 2
```

Note that the first one uses `>` to create a new file, and the rest use `>>` to append to the file, rather than overwriting it. The `2>&1` sends stderr to the same place stdout is going, so if you don't want to capture errors, omit that.

Also, I switched to a lowercase `date` variable; there are a bunch of all-caps variable names with special meanings, so it's safest to use lower- or mixed-case names to avoid conflicts. I double-quoted the filename because it contains a variable reference (not really needed here, but good scripting hygiene). Finally, I switched from using backticks to the cleaner `$()` for capturing output from the date command.

Another option is to redirect all of the script's output to the log file as it runs. You can do this without running the script again with the `exec` command. Note that you must do this *before* running the commands whose output you want redirected:

```
#!/bin/bash

date=$(/bin/date +"%Y%m%d%H%M")
exec >"stat-tps_${date}.txt" 2>&1    # Redirect output from this point on

#140 Caliper VM- Volte
sleep 2
./linux_machine_cli_firing.exp 172.9.9.14 "cd /root/cal/Product/run" "./cli -p  4001 " "show  call-mode statistics"
sleep 2
...
```

Again, omit the `2>&1` if you don't want to capture errors along with regular output.

Comment: Might want to redirect stderr while you're at it.

Comment: @glennjackman Good point; I'll do an edit.

Comment: Thanks Guys, I really appreciate all the help.